# Creating a WCF Client Inheriting from ClientBase in F#

Tags: wcf, inheritance, f#, c#-to-f#

I found the following code on the msdn site here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733133.aspx#Y380

```
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace="http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples", ConfigurationName="ICalculator")]
public interface ICalculator
{
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples/ICalculator/Add", ReplyAction="http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples/ICalculator/AddResponse")]
    double Add(double n1, double n2);

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples/ICalculator/Subtract", ReplyAction="http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples/ICalculator/SubtractResponse")]
    double Subtract(double n1, double n2);

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples/ICalculator/Multiply", ReplyAction="http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples/ICalculator/MultiplyResponse")]
    double Multiply(double n1, double n2);

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples/ICalculator/Divide", ReplyAction="http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples/ICalculator/DivideResponse")]
    double Divide(double n1, double n2);
}

public interface ICalculatorChannel : ICalculator, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel
{
}

public partial class CalculatorClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<ICalculator>, ICalculator
{

    public CalculatorClient()
    {
    }

    public CalculatorClient(string endpointConfigurationName) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName)
    {
    }

    public CalculatorClient(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress)
    {
    }

    public CalculatorClient(string endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress)
    {
    }

    public CalculatorClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(binding, remoteAddress)
    {
    }

    public double Add(double n1, double n2)
    {
        return base.Channel.Add(n1, n2);
    }

    public double Subtract(double n1, double n2)
    {
        return base.Channel.Subtract(n1, n2);
    }

    public double Multiply(double n1, double n2)
    {
        return base.Channel.Multiply(n1, n2);
    }

    public double Divide(double n1, double n2)
    {
        return base.Channel.Divide(n1, n2);
    }
}
```

Obviously, this is the world famous WCF CalculatorService on msdn.  The code I have shown above was generated with svcutil.exe.  However, svcutil.exe does not generate F# code so I'm trying to translate CalculatorClient into F# (I can handle the interfaces just fine).  I would show you what I have so far, except I only have the first three lines completed and those are probably wrong anyhow (I get that impression from all the red squigglyness decorating it).  I'm completely stumped by the combination of inheriting from a base class and an interface at the same time.  I don't need the whole class translated, just the class with a few constructors and one of the interface methods, and I'm sure I can work out the rest.  Although, if you want to translate the whole thing for posterity please feel free.

Thanks,

Bob

Edit:  Here is the interface I am using.  Feel free to edit it if it could be improved.

```
[<ServiceContract>]  
type ICalculator =
  [<OperationContract>]
  abstract member Add: float*float -> float
  [<OperationContract>]
  abstract member Subtract: float*float -> float
  [<OperationContract>]
  abstract member Multiply: float*float -> float
  [<OperationContract>]
  abstract member Divide: float*float -> float
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a rough stab at it:

```
type CalculatorClient =
    inherit System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<ICalculator>
    new() = 
        { inherit System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<ICalculator>() }
    new(name:string) = 
        { inherit System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<ICalculator>(name) }
    new(name:string, remoteAddress:string) = 
        { inherit System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<ICalculator>(name, remoteAddress) }
    new(name:string, remoteAddress:System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress) = 
        { inherit System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<ICalculator>(name, remoteAddress) }
    new(binding:System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding, remoteAddress) = 
        { inherit System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<ICalculator>(binding, remoteAddress) }
    member x.Add(n1,n2) = base.Channel.Add(n1,n2)
    member x.Subtract(n1,n2) = base.Channel.Subtract(n1,n2)
    member x.Multiply(n1,n2) = base.Channel.Multiply(n1,n2)
    member x.Divide(n1,n2) = base.Channel.Divide(n1,n2)
    interface ICalculator with
        // call into the methods on the class - these are *not* recursive
        member x.Add(n1,n2) = x.Add(n1,n2)
        member x.Subtract(n1,n2) = x.Subtract(n1,n2)
        member x.Multiply(n1,n2) = x.Multiply(n1,n2)
        member x.Divide(n1,n2) = x.Divide(n1,n2)
```

Comment: A rare case where you need to use the non-primary-constructor F# class syntax - when you want to have multiple constructors that each call into different base class constructors.

Comment: @Brian - I think that was why I was baffled on this one.

Comment: @kvb - You always make it look so simple!  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @kvb - When I write this code: let client = new CalculatorClient()
let addValue = client.Add(3,5) I get "The constructor or method Add is not defined".

Comment: @Beaker - in F#, all interface implementations are explicit, so you either need to upcast `client` to `ICalculator`, or you need to add additional `Add`, `Subtract`, etc. members.  I'll edit my answer to demonstrate the latter possibility.

Comment: @kvb - Thanks, I had forgotten about that little issue in F#.  I also posted the interface I'm using underneath my question.  Using tuples the way I am feels wrong to me, but technically works.  Feel free to edit it if it should be done differently.